# OLS model calibration with rms package

Tags: r, calibration, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to perform a calibration of an OLS model using bootstrapping with 1000 replications (`rms` package). Interestingly, I have no problem using the default 40 replications, but when I go up to e.g. 100, I get the following text:

> Error in lowess(x, y, iter = 0) : 'delta' must be finite and > 0

If I run the command repeatedly (about 10 times), I could overcome this issue, but if I want go to e.g. 500 replications, I have to re-run the code about 100 times. Unfortunately, I have to do it with 1000 replications, and no matter how many times I re-run it, I never get the result. Any ideas?

here is the script:

```
fit <- ols( stiffness ~ cap + cd4 + cd8 + age + BMI + cd48 + diabetes + 
                         hypertonia + triglicerid + cholesterin + 
                         lipodystrophia + betegsegfennalla + darunavir + 
                         atanazavir + raltegravir + etravirine + 
                         nevirapine + efavirenz + tenofovir + abacavir + 
                         zidovudine + lamivudine + lopinavir,
             data = S[!is.na( S$cholesterin ) & !is.na( S$betegsegfennalla ) & 
                      !is.na(S$triglicerid ) & !is.na( S$hypertonia ) & 
                      !is.na( S$BMI ), ], 
             x = TRUE, y = TRUE ) 

plot( calibrate( fit, B = 1000 ) )
```

> Error in lowess(x, y, iter = 0) : 'delta' must be finite and > 0